# TotalFinder like visor window alternative

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

I've been using TotalFinder for years now, but they no longer support the newer versions of MacOS.  What I use *a lot* is the visor with a shortcut key, which I have a dedicated key bound to on my keyboard.

Is there a way to have either Finder, or one of the finder alternatives (e.g. Forklift or Marta) behave in the same way where a keyboard shortcut can be set to open the application, but where the application automatically hides the moment it loses focus?  I'm essentially looking for a similar behaviour to the hotkey in iTerm, but for finder or a finder alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I've had an experience, with TotalFinder. I've been on a quest to find a replacement that has the Visor feature. While Forklift and Marta are alternatives I found that Commander One stands out because it can replicate the Visor behavior using a customizable keyboard shortcut. Try different software, maybe you will find something exactly useful for you

Answer (score 1):

This is one I've long struggled with. TotalFinder with Visor was my go-to for about a decade. The shortfalls with most alternatives are...

1. The ability to show/hide with shortcut with an animation from the bottom edge of the screen, appearing on top of the existing app.
2. Hides when not focused
3. Lightweight, simple and inline with macOS aesthetic
4. Works with Stage Manager

That fourth one is the killer really. I found [FastFinder](https://github.com/AnthoPakPak/FastFinder) that animates Finder in a similar fashion, but it is 4 years old without updates and probably doesn't even factor in Stage Manager since it hadn't been released yet.

I find most of the other ones are often ugly and trying to reinvent the wheel on Finder, when really all I'm looking for is something that allows me to access files quickly, seamlessly and just goes away quickly when not needed. And has tabs and doesn't result in 10 different Finder panels open simultaneously. I'm not looking for an app that  needs all the bells and whistles.

The one that has hit closest for me functionality-wise is [QSpace Pro](https://qspace.awehunt.com/en-us/index.html). It's not perfect, but can set the shortcut to show, and can be customized to look like Finder on steroids, which was essentially what TotalFinder did.